# How to convert human voice to musical note in Android?

Tags: android, open-source, opensl, aubio

I am trying to store analog data from Android mike to musical notes such as a4,b1.. I tried working with [aubio.org](http://aubio.org/) . But its written in C. Is there any other open source for doing it. If aubio is the way to do it how can i do it.

Comment: You can port it to android by NDK

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this project - [audio2midi](https://code.google.com/p/audio2midi/) integrating aubio in android.

Comment: I am checking on it, I hope it helps me. Thanks for helping.